# Search in Arraylist with content of an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I´m trying to search if my arraylist, "lottoraws", contain the integers that my random array, c, have. I want to print how many numbers of the array, c, which is into the arraylist. Which tells how many corrects there are into lottoraw.

//Code:

```
lottoraws=new ArrayList<int []>();
 }

public void addLottoraws(int 5) { // for example 5

    int[] a = {};

//------------------------Generate random numbers into arraylist

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        a = new int[7];

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            int rand = (int) (random.nextInt(35));
            a[j] = rand;
        }
        lottoraws.add(a);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < lottoraws.size(); k++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lottoraws.get(k)));
    }

    // -------------------------Generate random numbers into array
    int[] c = new int[7];

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 35 + 1);
        c[j] = rand;
    }
    System.out.println("Dragen rad: \n" + Arrays.toString(c));

    //------------------------...--..-.-.-.-.-.---------Show result
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you only want the count of the common numbers or the numbers itself

Comment: I just want to search for the numbers in "c" and then print how many of them that are in the arraylist. So only print the countervalue. Its it possible to print at value between 0-7 depending on the randomgen.

Comment: yes @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala

Comment: please, please name your variables accordingly, not like a, b, c, etc...

Comment: The code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
In the below method counterMap will have the number as well its count.

        Random random = new Random();
        List lottoraws = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

//         int[] a1 = new int[7];

            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                int rand = (int) (random.nextInt(35));
//              a1[j] = rand;
                lottoraws.add(rand);
            }

        } // at the end of this loop, our list will have 35 elements. 

        for (int k = 0; k < lottoraws.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println(lottoraws.get(k));
        }

        // -------------------------Generate random numbers into array
        int[] c = new int[7];

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 35 + 1);
            c[j] = rand;
        } // our array will now have 7 random numbers
        System.out.println("Dragen rad: \n" + Arrays.toString(c));

        Map counterMap = new HashMap();

        for(int i=0;i<lottoraws.size();i++){
            int lstNum = (int) lottoraws.get(i);
            int searchCount = Arrays.binarySearch(c, lstNum);
            if(searchCount>-1){
                if(counterMap.containsKey(lstNum)){
//                  System.out.println("found");
                    int counterInc = (int)counterMap.get(lstNum);
                    counterMap.put(lstNum,++counterInc);
                } else
                    counterMap.put(lstNum,1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counterMap);
```

Comment: ok thanks, but is there a way to do this without using Hashmap? @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala

Comment: you can avoid map, by using an array equisized to that of "c". initialize all fields with zero and increment the filed where lstNum is present. once the loop terminates you need to run another loop and filter out only non-zero fields map it to "c" and find out the occurrence of each number.

This would be complex, thus I prefer a map.

Comment: Maybe something like this:   


  int count1 =0;

  for (int j = 0; j < lottoraws.size(); j++) {


  if (lottoraws.get(j) == c[j]){
   count1++;

  else{
   System.out.println("not found");}

  
  }

Comment: you need to have the as many number of variables as the length of "c", not a good practice.

Comment: I don´t understand the maps so i prefer to do it with an simple if{} Is it possible?

Comment: Map is simple, 

For the sake of understanding:
1.Assume an array with two fields. first will have the key and other will have the value for the key.

2. Now make a list of this array
3. when we invoke the put method, we pass the key (populated in the first field) and value (populated in the second field)
4. get in turn finds the scans through the first cell of the array and returns the value stored in the second